# Travelling from USA to Australia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, regulations, indian-citizens

I am on H1B and travelling to Australia on my permanent residency visa. Since I am a Indian citizen / passport are there any additional formalities that needs to be done?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Permanent Residency Visa from which country?  Are you connecting anywhere?  What kind of formalities are you referring to?

Comment: You most likely already know that but you also need to ensure you have the required visa, if any, for any stopover on the way to Australia.

Answer (score 4):

If your Permanent Residency Visa is for Australia, not an equivalent for the USA like I'd originally assumed, then you just need to make sure you have a "[valid travel authority](http://www.immi.gov.au/Live/Pages/australian-permanent-resident-information.aspx)" for your visa.  In general that's automatic as part of the visa.

If the visa was referring to the USA, as Indian nationals are not able to get [Electronic Travel Authority](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/601.aspx) or [eVisitor](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/651.aspx) visas you will need to apply for a [Visitor visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/600.aspx).

The last link provides the details, but in summary you need to apply for the visa outside Australia and meet health and "character" requirements, i.e. not been arrested recently.

You will need to make sure you [bring the following information to be able to return](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~ovis/updates/h1b/travel.html) to the USA:

> If you travel out of the U.S. while you are in H status, you should
>   have the following documents in order to be re-admitted to the U.S.
>
> Passport valid 6 months into the future
>   Letter from department Chair
>   or Dean confirming current employment in same position described in
>   his / her H petition
>   Recent check-stubs proving current employment at
>   employer sponsor
>   Copy of complete H-1B petition filed with the CIS 
>   Valid Form I-797 H Approval Notice (Request the top portion of this
>   form from the Office of Visa and Immigration Services. Please return
>   this to the Office of Visa and Immigration Services upon your return.
>
> If appropriate, original J-1 home residency I-612 Waiver Approval
>   Notice (only applies to former J-1 holders who were subject to the two
>   year home residency requirement)
>   Valid H visa for re-entry to U.S.

Comment: I am going to presume that his "Permanent Residency Visa" is for Australia, given that there is no such thing for the US...  Obviously we will need to wait for Amit to reply to confirm that.

Comment: True.  Interesting combination if that is the case, which is why I didn't think of it.